# Python: read command line args with argparse in addition to those coming from an external function

Tags: python, argparse

I have two modules in the same package, `module1.py` and `module2.py`.

In `module1.py` I have a function reading command-line args with `argparse`:

```
import argparse

def parse_arguments_module1():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    optional = parser._action_groups.pop()
    required = parser.add_argument_group('required arguments')
    required.add_argument('--argA', help='argA', required=True)
    required.add_argument('--argB', help='argB', required=True)
    optional.add_argument('--argC', help='argC')
    optional.add_argument('--argD', help='argD')
    parser._action_groups.append(optional)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args
```

Now suppose in `module2.py` I import `parse_arguments_module1()` from `module1.py` and use it (this works):

```
from module1 import parse_arguments_module1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parse_arguments_module1()
    print(args)
```

Use:

```
python3 module2.py --argA A --argB B --argC C
```

Output:

> Namespace(argA='A', argB='B', argC='C', argD=None)

The question is: how to read arguments in `module2.py` (`required` and/or `optional`) *additional* to those of `module1.py`? (I.e. have `args` in `main` contain more arguments, just for `module2.py`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to use [*partial parsing*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#partial-parsing) with [`parser.parse_known_args()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_known_args) to achieve what you want, and / or pass your arguments as a list, explicitly.

Normally, without arguments `parser.parse_args()` takes all values from `sys.argv[1:]` (so everything but the first element) as the input to parse. If there are elements in that list that can't be parsed, then an error message is printed and `sys.exit(1)` is called; your script would exit.

So if you want *some* arguments on `sys.argv` to go to one parser, and the remainder to another, you want to use `parser.parse_known_args()` and pass the remainder to the other parser.

I'd split out creating and configuring the `ArgumentParser()` instances from parsing; so in `module1` do:

```
def module1_argument_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    optional = parser._action_groups.pop()
    required = parser.add_argument_group('required arguments')
    required.add_argument('--argA', help='argA', required=True)
    required.add_argument('--argB', help='argB', required=True)
    optional.add_argument('--argC', help='argC')
    optional.add_argument('--argD', help='argD')
    parser._action_groups.append(optional)
    return parser

def parse_arguments_module1(args=None):
    parser = module1_argument_parser()
    return parser.parse_args(args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parse_arguments_module1()
    print(args)
```

and in `module2`, use the same structure, but re-use the parser from `module1`:

```
from module1 import module1_argument_parser

def module2_argument_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    # create argument switches, etc.
    return parser

def parse_arguments_module2(args=None):
    parser = module2_argument_parser()
    return parser.parse_args(args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    module1_parser = module1_argument_parser()
    module1_args, remainder = module1_parser.parse_known_args()
    module2_args = parse_arguments_module2(remainder)
    print(module1_args)
    print(module2_args)
```