# Configuring logging from ArgParser and/or PyCharm

Tags: python, logging, pycharm, argparse

It's not hard to code [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) so it sets up a [basicConfig](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) with a lower `level` if the user supplies, say, a `--verbose` flag. Numerous StackOverflow questions address this.

But it seems like a lot of coding, for what seems like a pretty everyday use case. I would've thought somebody would've written a nice library that can set up an `ArgParser` to allow users to specify all sorts of [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) options from the command line, with just a couple of lines of code.

I've also recently started using [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/), and was surprised that, out of the box, messages sent to `logger.debug` and even `logger.info` don't appear in the console. I imagined there'd be some PyCharm-related library I could import, to set up logging in some easily configurable, PyCharm-friendly way, when my program is being run within PyCharm.

Am I expecting too much, am I overlooking a Python feature, or am I just having a bad Google day? Do standard libraries exist for these things?

(A note for the off-topic police: I've asked whether *standard* libraries exist, and not for 'recommendations'.)

Comment: Anything on Pypi?  That's as close to being 'standard' without being part of the main Python distribution.

Comment: I'm a little puzzled about your goal.  Even if you found a parser that accepted a bunch of the logging parameters, how would you incorporate that with parsing application specific values?  Using the `parents` mechanism?  A standalone parser that uses `parse_known_args`?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52929014/python-read-command-line-args-with-argparse-in-addition-to-those-coming-from-an

Comment: To be honest, I don't think that `parser = ArgumentParser(); parser.add_argument('--verbose', action='count', default=0); levels = [logging.ERROR, logging.WARN, logging.INFO, logging.DEBUG]; logging.basicConfig(level=levels[parser.parse_args().verbose])` deserves a special library just for that, recalling the `npm left-pad` story. However, there are lots of third-party libraries that are wrapping the stdlib code, what comes to mind is `click` with the `click-log` plugin, or `pycli`; you can try them out.

Comment: @hpaulj: Something like that, yeah. I'm not exactly sure about what the details would be, but I've written utility libraries that accept `ArgParsers` myself, and I imagined this is something a buncho' bright people would've already done the thinking for.

Comment: @hoefling: If it were just that, I'd agree with you. But there's more to the logging module than levels: filenames, formatters, etc. In any case, the only way I know to get PyCharm to display what I send to `logger.debug` or even `logger.info` is to write more code, and that smells. But maybe my code-nose is oversensitive. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a couple of standard ways to configure logging from files. Hopefully PyCharm will eventually have plug-ins with nice GUIs for creating these files.

## `fileConfig()`—The Simplest Way

Use a [FileType argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#filetype-objects) for ArgParse, for use as the logger's [`fileConfig()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.fileConfig).

```
import argparse
import logging
import logging.config

argument_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
argument_parser.add('--logging-conf-path', type=argparse.FileType('r'), 
        help='path to logging configuration file',
        default='./logging.conf',
)
args = argument_parser.parse_args()
if args.logging_conf_path:
    logging.config.fileConfig(args.logging_conf_path.name)
```

It does come with this caveat, though:

> **Note:** The [`fileConfig()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.fileConfig) API is older than the [`dictConfig()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.dictConfig) API and does not provide functionality to cover certain aspects of logging. For example, you cannot configure [`Filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Filter) objects, which provide for filtering of messages beyond simple integer levels, using [`fileConfig()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.fileConfig). If you need to have instances of [`Filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Filter) in your logging configuration, you will need to use [`dictConfig()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.dictConfig). Note that future enhancements to configuration functionality will be added to [`dictConfig()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.dictConfig), so it’s worth considering transitioning to this newer API when it’s convenient to do so.

But here's an [example](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging) of a logging.conf file, which follows the [logging configuration file format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging-config-fileformat) (which is where the caveat is noted):

```
[loggers]
keys=root,simpleExample

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler

[logger_simpleExample]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler
qualname=simpleExample
propagate=0

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=
```

## `dictConfig()`—The Complete Way

This uses the `dictConfig()` recommended in the caveat above. Since my program already uses YAML files for configuration, I read the dict using [PyYAML](https://pyyaml.org/)

```
import argparse
import logging
import logging.config
import yaml

argument_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
argument_parser.add('--logging-yaml-path', type=argparse.FileType('r'), 
        help='path to logging configuration file',
        default='./logging.yaml',
)
args = argument_parser.parse_args()
if args.logging_yaml_path:
    log_config = yaml.load(args.logging_yaml_path)
    logging.config.dictConfig(log_config)
```

And here's an example of a logging.yaml file, which follows the [logging configuration dictionary schema](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging-config-dictschema):

```
version: 1
formatters:
  brief:
    format: '%(message)s'
  default:
    format: '%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(name)-15s %(message)s'
    datefmt: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
handlers:
  console:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    level: WARN
    formatter: brief
    stream: ext://sys.stdout
  file:
    class : logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
    formatter: default
    filename: ./gmartian.log
    when: w0
    backupCount: 6
root:
  level: INFO
  handlers:
  - console
  - file
```